# Assets\mqtthandler.cs(59,26): error CS7069: Reference to type 'IPAddress' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, visual-studio-2019

I made a MQTT Client using the M2MQTT Library in Unity for Microsoft Hololens but i can't build the Unity project with error "Assets\mqtthandler.cs(59,26): error CS7069: Reference to type 'IPAddress' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found".

I need to build it to deploy it to Hololens Emulator.

In my script mqtthandler.cs the brokerHostname in my code somehow induces this error when trying to create an MQTTClient. Visual Studio sees no error in this script, only when trying to build my project in Unity i geht this error in the Unity console.

If i run my project in Unity itself i can successfully receive mqtt messages.

I've already reimported all assets, cleared Unity cache, regenerated the M2MQTT.NET.dll.

I am using Unity 2018.3 and Visual Studio 2019.

My code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System;
using UnityEngine;


// including the M2Mqtt Library
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;



public class mqtthandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MqttClient client;
    // The connection information
    public string brokerHostname = "127.0.0.1";
    public int brokerPort = 1883;
    public string userName = "test";
    public string password = "test";
    public static string messageOutput;
    public static string topicOutput;
    //public TextAsset certificate;
    // listen on all the Topic
    static string subTopic = "#";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (brokerHostname != null && userName != null && password !=null)
        {
            Debug.Log("connecting to " + brokerHostname + ":" + brokerPort);
            Connect();
            client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
            byte[] qosLevels = { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE };
            client.Subscribe(new string[] { subTopic }, qosLevels);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void Connect()
    {
        Debug.Log("about to connect on '" + brokerHostname + "'");
        // Forming a certificate based on a TextAsset
        /*X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate();
        cert.Import(certificate.bytes);
        Debug.Log("Using the certificate '" + cert + "'");*/
        client = new MqttClient(brokerHostname/*, brokerPort, false, null, true, cert, null, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_0, MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback*/);
        string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Debug.Log("About to connect using '" + userName + "' / '" + password + "'");
        try
        {
            client.Connect(clientId, userName, password);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Connection error: " + e);
        }
    }

    void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    {
        string msg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
        Debug.Log("Received message from " + e.Topic + " : " + msg);
        messageOutput = msg;
        topicOutput = e.Topic;
    }

    private void Publish(string _topic, string msg)
    {
        client.Publish(
            _topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg),
            MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_MOST_ONCE, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a solution, add it as an answer (in the box under the question). Do not edit the title to include "FIXED", this is what an accepted answer is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved: I had to build the M2MQTT.WinRT.dll and import it into the Assets folder as well. Now i can successfully build the Unity Project.